# Regex match only if text contains something before

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Given the following text

```
KEYWORD This is a test
We want to match the following groups 1:YES 2:YES 3:YES
```

I want to match with "`1:YES`", "`2:YES`" and "`3:YES`" using

```
((\d):YES)
```

If and only if the first word in the complete text is "`KEYWORD`"

Given this test:

```
This is a test
We want to match the following groups 1:YES 2:YES 3:YES
```

No matches should be found

Comment: If you show the Java code you are currently using, it could make the answer simpler (a combination of regex and logic).

Comment: It seems you are trying to do something similar to this [`\A(?=KEYWORD)[\s\S]*?((?:\d:YES\s*)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/1UaBxl/1)

Comment: Sometimes it's way easier and clearer to read if you don't try to use one regex for everything. You could first match for `KEYWORD`, and then match and extract all the other groups.

Answer (score 3):

Java (as with most regex engines) doesn't support unbounded length look behinds, however there is a work-around!

```
String str = "KEYWORD This is a test\n" +
        "We want to match the following groups 1:YES 2:YES 3:YES";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=\\AKEYWORD\\b.{1,99999})(\\d+:YES)").matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1:YES
2:YES
3:YES
```

The trick here is the look behind `(?<=\\AKEYWORD.{1,99999})` which has a large (but not unbounded) length. `(?s)` means DOTALL flag (dot matches newline too) and `\A` means start of input which is needed because `^` matches start of line when DOTALL flag is used.

Comment: The non-capture group around `\\d+` isn't actually needed. Also, `\b` *may* be important to use after `KEYWORD`. Nice answer though +1

Comment: @ctwheels I thought I would improve OP's regex which captured the digit, but didn't stop to think that it wasn't needed... duh. I added `\b` - good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Without tricking lookbhinds in Java you can capture `\d+:YES\b` strings with using `\G`. `\G` causes a match to start from where previous match ended or it will match beginning of string the same as `\A`.

We are in need of its first capability:

```
(?:\AKEYWORD|\G(?!\A))[\s\S]*?(\d:YES\b)
```

Breakdown:

- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `\A` Match beginning of subject string
  - `KEYWORD` Match keyword
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Continue from where previous match ends
- `)` End of NCG
- `[\s\S]*?` Match anything else un-greedily
- `(\d+:YES\b)` Match and capture our desired part

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/xb4R7B/1)

Java code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\AKEYWORD|\\G(?!\\A))[\\s\\S]*?(\\d+:YES\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);                                   
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/P3zA3c)

Comment: Agree, better idea to use `\G`